# Restkit object mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm struggling trying to map the following json response:

```
{
 "data":
       {
        "plans":
          [
           {
             "planid":"10",
             "plandescription":"foo",
             "plantype":"2",
             "planvalue":"30",
             "status":"Active"
           }
         ]
       }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
RKObjectMapping *planMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Plans class]];
[planMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"planid": @"planId",
 @"plandescription": @"planDescription",
 @"plantype": @"planType",
 @"planvalue": @"planValue",
 @"status" : @"status"
 }];

RKResponseDescriptor *planResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:planMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"data/plans" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:planResponseDescriptor];
```

Yet the object doesn't get mapped :\ What is wrong?

Comment: Did you get it fix or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing keyPath:@"data/plans" to keyPath:@"data.plans"